# github actions failed to push to another repo

Tags: git, github, github-actions

In `myCurrentRepo`, I want to push to the `test` repo.

my yml:

```
...
jobs:
    main:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3 #checkout current repo
        # ...
        # do something with current repo
        # ...

        - uses: actions/setup-node@v2 
          with:
            node-version: "16"
        - name: Checkout test repo #checkout test repo
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            repository: myOrg/test
            fetch-depth: 0
            path: "test"
            ref: "develop"
            token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
        - name: Run script
          run: sh ${{ env.SCRIPT_DOT_SH }}
        - name: update dependencies
          run: npm i # I found the issue here, current repo is running npm i, not test repo, why?
        - name: Commit change
          run: |
            git config --global user.name 'someone'
            git config --global user.email 'someone@myOrg.com'
            git commit -am "some words"
            git push origin develop
```

But I noticed in the `npm i` it runs `npm i` not on the `test` repo but the current repo. That's why my commit has errors like

```
error: failed to push some refs to https://github.com/myOrg/myCurrentRepo
```

I've spent hours struggling with this, is there any wrong with my sequence?

Comment: Does your script `my_script_to_make_some_changes.sh` make changes to `test` repo? You need to verify where your commands are running. Maybe, you need to run `cd test` first to go into that directory.

Comment: my_script_to_make_some_changes.sh is stored in `myCurrentRepo` and I want to execute it on `test` repo. It should run in test repo no? because I place it after `Checkout test repo`

Comment: Right. Then, it should be somewhere at `../myCurrentRepo/my_script_to_make_some_changes.sh` after you checked out the `test` repo. You need to adjust that accordingly.

Comment: @Azeem I updated my description, it was stored earlier, I don't think that's the problem though. It's used to modify file in test repo, and it succeed.

Comment: You can add `pwd` and `ls` commands to your `Run script` step to check what directory the commands are run in.

Comment: @ViennaJ: Well, if the paths are correct, then the only thing left is the `git push` and that's where that error is coming from. Have you configured both repos (e.g. via SSH public/private) so that the `git push` can be performed?

Comment: the issue isn't `git push` but something is wrong at `npm i`. It's installing myCurrentRepo, not on the test repo.

Comment: @ViennaJ: Your above comment is not what you said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105431/github-actions-failed-to-push-to-another-repo#comment132537779_75105431) earlier that "**I don't think that's the problem though. It's used to modify file in test repo, and it succeed.**". But, clearly, the paths need to be verified with `pwd` and `ls` as mentioned before. `npm i` needs to run in the correct directory.

Comment: @Azeem ok my bad, I tried pwd, I didn't see it switched to the test repo. Wierd.

Comment: You need to change directory on each steps

Comment: @ViennaJ: Glad you could find it. You can switch to it with `cd` whenever required. Anyways, it was a side issue. Once this is fixed on your side, please update on the actual `git push` issue whether it's still there or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each run keyword represents a new process and shell in the runner environment. So on each step the current directory is the working directory.

```yaml
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: [push]
jobs:
    main:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - name: Run script
          run: pwd && cd /tmp && pwd && ls
        - name: Run another script
          run: pwd && ls
```

```
Run pwd && cd /tmp && pwd && ls
/home/runner/work/test/test
/tmp
[...]
Run pwd && ls
/home/runner/work/test/test
[...]
```

You have to set the directory for each steps
you can use `cd` or set a working directory for the step

Example:

```yaml
- name: Clean temp directory
  run: rm -rf *
  working-directory: ./temp
```

```yaml
- name: Clean temp directory
  run: |
       cd temp 
       rm -rf *
```

To test, this script

```yaml
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: [push]
jobs:
    main:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - name: Run script
          run: pwd && cd /tmp && pwd
        - name: Run another script
          run: pwd
        - name: multi
          run: |
               cd /tmp
               pwd
        - name: Run workdir
          run: pwd
          working-directory: /tmp
```

will give you

[image: github action]

Comment: this is crazy, why can't I just checkout a repo and do working-directory: 'test' every time?

Comment: you can change the default working dir too to have this for each steps https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-set-the-default-shell-and-working-directory